# Make sure deleted photos on an Ipod touch can never be recovered?

Tags: ipod, photos, macos

How can you make sure deleted photos on an Ipod touch 5 can never be restored or found by someone else?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting them should be good enough, but due to the iOS sandboxing restrictions, full deletion is not truly possible. However, recovering these photos would be extremely difficult and require extremely expensive software and a great deal of knowledge. After time, the picture files will be overwritten and then be truly inaccessible. Best advice: don't take/save pictures you'll later regret.